# Java: Print a diamond recursively

Tags: java, recursion

How would you print a diamond recursively using Java with only given the size?

A size of 5 produces:

```
 ***** *****
 ****   ****
 ***     ***
 **       **
 *         *

 *         *
 **       **
 ***     ***
 ****   ****
 ***** *****
```

Code I have so far

```
public static void dia(int statSize, int size,int count) {

      int statSizeLarge = (statSize*2)+1; 

      // Params:
      // statSize == static size, never change this
      // size == variable size, change this
      // count == counter

      if(size==0) {
              System.out.println(); 
      } else {

          // is the counter smaller then the size
          // if yes, increment and keep printing
          if(count<size){
              System.out.print("*");
          } 



          // is greater then size? 
          // if yes, move on, print 
          // a few more stars
              if((count<=statSizeLarge)){
                  if(count<statSize+1 && (count>size)){
                      System.out.print(" ");
                  }else if (count>size+1){
                      System.out.print("*");
                  } else {}
                  dia(statSize,size,count+1);
              }



         // reset count, move to next element
          if(count>=statSizeLarge) {
              count = 0; 
              System.out.println();
              dia(statSize,size-1,count);
          }



      } // ends Else  

  }
```

OutPut:

```
Enter commands:
diamond 3
******
** ****
*  ****




*  ****




** ****
*  ****




*  ****
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To create a larger diamond, take a smaller one and add two extra rows and columns. In the diagrom below I've replace spaces with dots for clarity. In the second diamond the newly added characters are shown in bold.

```
              *****.*****  <-- extra row
****.****     ****...****
***...***     ***.....***
**.....**     **.......**
*.......*     *.........*
......... --> ...........
*.......*     *.........*
**.....**     **.......**
***...***     ***.....***
****.****     ****...****
              *****.*****  <-- extra row
                   ^^
                   ||
                   extra columns
```

Your recursive function should print the first row, then print a smaller diamond with two extra columns in the middle, then the last row.

In pseudocode:

```
void diamond(stars, spaces) {
    if (n == 0) {
        print(' ' * spaces)
    } else {
        print('*' * stars, ' ' * spaces, '*' * stars)
        diamond(stars - 1, spaces + 2)
        print('*' * stars, ' ' * spaces, '*' * stars)
    }
}
```

Since this is a learning exercise I won't give you the full Java source code - you can have a go at writing it yourself. Here you can see it running online in Python, just so that you can see that the algorithm works:

- [ideone](http://ideone.com/iqLpZ)

Answer (score 1):

Hint: look for the pattern in the output.  Try to map that pattern onto recursive calls, where a method does something, calls itself, and then does something else.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the Java Program to print the diamond of stars:

```java
class DiamondPattern {
    static public int ReadInteger() {
        try {
            String inpString = "";
            InputStreamReader input = new InputStreamReader(System.in);
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(input);
            String s = reader.readLine();
            return Integer.parseInt(s);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return -1;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Program for displaying pattern of *.");
        System.out.print("Enter the maximum number of *: ");
        int n = ReadInteger();

        System.out.println("\nHere is the Diamond of Stars\n");

        for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < (n - i); j++)
                System.out.print(" ");
            for (int j = 1; j <= i; j++)
                System.out.print("*");
            for (int k = 1; k < i; k++)
                System.out.print("*");
            System.out.println();
        }

        for (int i = n - 1; i >= 1; i--) {
            for (int j = 0; j < (n - i); j++)
                System.out.print(" ");
            for (int j = 1; j <= i; j++)
                System.out.print("*");
            for (int k = 1; k < i; k++)
                System.out.print("*");
            System.out.println();
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```