# convert a diamond shape printing method to a recursive one

Tags: java, recursion, methods, shapes

Tonight we have to submit a project contains many methods,and one of them is to print a diamond with only odd numbers with spaces between them to have an output like this if the number was 3 :

```
  * 
* * * 
  *
```

```
public static void drawDiamond(int n)
{
    int q = n/2;
    for(int a = -q; a <= q ;a++) {
        int b = (a < 0)?-a:a;
        int c = q-b;
        for(int d = 0;d <= q+c;d++) {
            System.out.print((d < b)?" ":"*");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

well,I tried to write a method myself but I couldn't,just found this one and I need someone to help me to convert it to a recursive method..and thank you very much <3

Comment: You could start by trying to format your post and explaining what you have tried already.

Comment: You won't ever learn if you just keep "finding methods" we can help you but you shouldn't just copy and paste code you should try to figure out why this method works by debugging...If you want to become a developer you need to learn how to develop.  We have not problem helping you but you should atleast attempt something then we can point you in the right direction...

Comment: Look up articles on recursion it should get you started...

Comment: Please edit this question, if you have something new to say. Don't post the answer unless it is the answer.

Comment: Also this might help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5130442/java-print-a-diamond-recursively?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

public static String DiamondF(int num) //method1
    {
        if(num>0)
        {
            return "* " + DiamondF(num+2);
        }
        else
        {
            return " ";
        }
    }
     public static String DiamondS(int num)//method2
    {
        if(num>0)
        {
            return " * " + DiamondF(num+2);//access method1
        }
        else
        {
            return " ";
        }
    }

```
public static String Space(int num) //method3
{
    if(num>0)
    {
        return " " + Space(num+2);
    }
    else
    {
        return " ";
    }
}
public static void DiamondResult(int num)//method4
{
    for(int i=1; i<num; i++)
    {
        System.out.print(Space(num-i));//access method3
         System.out.println(DiamondF(i));//access method1

    }
     for(int i=0; i<num; i++)
    {
        System.out.println(DiamondS(num-i));//access method2
        System.out.print(Space(i));//access method3

    }
```

}

this one is totally wrong and gives me excaptions !

Answer (score 0):

public static String DiamondF(int

num) //method1

```
{

    if(num>0)

    {

        return "* " +
```

DiamondF(num+2);

```
    }

    else

    {

        return " ";

    }

}

 public static String DiamondS(int
```

num)//method2

```
{

    if(num>0)

    {

        return " * " +
```

DiamondF(num+2);//access method1

```
    }

    else

    {

        return " ";

    }

}

public static String Space(int num)
```

//method3

```
{

    if(num>0)

    {

        return " " + Space(num+2);

    }

    else

    {

        return " ";

    }

}

public static void DiamondResult(int
```

num)//method4

```
{

    for(int i=1; i<num; i++)

    {

        System.out.print(Space(num-i));//access method3

         System.out.println(DiamondF(i));//access method1


    }

     for(int i=0; i<num; i++)
    {

        System.out.println(DiamondS(num-i));//access method2

        System.out.print(Space(i));//access method3
```

}
        }

Answer (score 0):

Its very hard to understand what you want, cause your description

> to print a diamond with only odd numbers with spaces between them

and the figure you've posted

```
  * 
* * * 
  *
```

don't really match. Anyways, here is a very simple recursive code that prints a diamond, understand it, and work from there

```
static int iteration = 1;
private static void drawDiamond(int n) {
    String row = new String(new char[iteration]).replace("\0", "*"); // create a string with '*' repating n times
    iteration++;
    if (iteration <= n) {
        System.out.println(row);
        drawDiamond(n);
    }
    System.out.println(row);
}
```

prints

```
*
**
***
**
*
```